# Division Operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to return 3 as a result of ((5168/2000) .
I'm using CEILING(5168/2000) to delete rows. Its returning 2. But I want 3.
So that loop execute for 3 times.

Comment: Use `CEILING(1.0*5168/2000)` as SQL Server does integer division by default.

Comment: Can also Achieve this way `select cast(round(5168.00/2000.00,0) as decimal(18,0))`

Comment: `SELECT CAST(ROUND((CAST(5168 AS DECIMAL)/CAST(2000 AS DECIMAL)), 0) AS INT)`

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the mentioned post as problem here is using integer division instead of floating point division.

Comment: You should post your real code. If the number is `COUNT(*)`, as you mention in a comment, then the real code is probably `CEILING(COUNT(*)/2000)`. Otherwise it is difficult to give you the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to return 3 as a result of (5168/2000)

Yes, make sure you're diving floating point numbers not integers

```
CEILING(5168.0/2000)
```

One way to achive that, aside from hardcoding the `.0` as I have above, is to cast your integer to an appropriate type, for example:

```
CEILING(CAST(5168 AS FLOAT)/2000)
```

or muultiply it by a decimal

```
 CEILING((1.0 * 5168)/2000)
```

Comment: But that number is COUNT(*) from table. So to change the variable type will solve the problem? Like DECLARE @cnt  float

Comment: @Sana01 - Ummm, perhaps you should try it?

Comment: @Sana01 you probably want to `CAST` your count as a floating point number. See the update to this answer if you've not refreshed.

Comment: @Jamiec - Could also maintain integer division *(slightly cheaper in the CPU, probably irrelevant)* by using `(x + n - 1) / n` to give the answer rounded up...   *`(5168 + 1999) / 2000 = 3`*

Comment: @MatBailie yep. You could indeed.